# My Tickets Wordpress plugin forcing tickets in cart

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress website with the MyCalendar and MyTicket plugins for an event. However, anytime someone tries to purchase tickets, the cart automatically populates with the two ticket options. Any idea why this is happening? Here's the site:
https://dhincc.org/
https://dhincc.org/purchase/

Comment: It is obvious that to buy the tickets you need to add them to your cart and do a checkout.  
Can you also include in your question what should happen instead?

Comment: The cart, when looked at in Incognito mode, immediately has two ticket items in the cart. Even when starting on the homepage in Incognito and then going to purchase one ticket, it still shows both inside the cart. There should be no items in the cart when the link I attached is clicked but it's always full.

Comment: I see empty cart when landing on cart page.